# Error building openframeworks for android: “ invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Poco::Path’”

Tags: android, c++, openframeworks

I am trying to build an android application with OF. The application runs in two other computers. However, it does not work on mine. I am using a mac.

I run the command "make AndroidDebug" in the project folder, and this is the error I have:

```
/Library/openFrameworks/addons/ofxHTTP/libs/ofxHTTP/src/PostRouteFileHandler.cpp:98:46: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Poco::Path'
                 ss << Poco::Path(formFileName).getExtension();
```

I have installed poco, but nothing changes afterwards.

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included Poco/Path.h?

A forward declaration might appeared earlier (possibly in another header) without complete definition.